# Need a batch program to install all manually downloaded Windows Updates in one single click

Tags: windows-8, updates

I got some pre-installed Windows 8 PC. I don't want to automatically download the same updates for all PC again and again which will reduce my internet speed. 
So, I have manually downloaded the Window Update (.msu extenstion).

The problem is there are total of 163 updates. I don't have time and energy to click Next > Install > Close for 163 times. I want to install in just one single click using my downloaded .msu update files.

I have tried some third party applications but those doesn't seem to help me.

Appreciate all the help and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [How to Install a .msu Update on Windows 7 from the Command Line](https://kb.cscc.edu/article/how-to-install-a-msu-update-on-windows-7-from-the-command-line-63.html):

> To install an `.msu` update package, run `Wusa.exe` together with the full
>   path of the file:
>
> - If `Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu` is within `D:\934307\`, install the update package via: 
>    `wusa d:\934307\Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu`
> - To run without user interaction, use the `/quiet` switch (auto-reboots if required). 
>    `wusa d:\934307\Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu /quiet`
>
>   - When using this switch, Microsoft's Software License Terms do not appear.
>   - To prevent an auto-reboot, use the `/norestart` switch, which is ignored if `/quiet` is not present (if installation requires a reboot, Windows must be manually rebooted): 
>      `wusa D:\934307\Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu /quiet /norestart`

Using this format, run the following batch file contents from within the folder containing the updates:

```bat
Set Folder="C:\updates"
for %%f in (%Folder%\*.msu) do (
  wusa.exe %%f /quiet /norestart
)
```

Notes:

- You can check whether the `.bat` file worked or not by trying to manually install the update; Windows Update should reply `Update already installed on this computer`.
- If you see nothing works after running the batch file, delete `/quiet` to see the error report.

Comment: Will test your method and reply you back ASAP :)

Comment: Wow!!!!!!!! It worked after I made some corrections to your code. Kudos to you, bro. You saved my time and energy.
Can I edit your answer for other people's reference? @Sir Adelaide

Comment: sure, go ahead_

Comment: Done, my savior. :)