# Need a batch program to install all manually downloaded Windows Updates .exe files

Tags: windows-10

I Installed new Windows 10 and installed updates. After scanning for vulnerability we wanted to install 60+ patches on 20+ machines , we downloaded those patches as exe and unable to install in all the machines manually.

I have tried some scripts which supports msu, but it fails as it is exe files.

Appreciate all the help and answers.

Comment: If the Windows 10 systems are located in the same subnet all systems don't need to download the patches, Windows 10 has a built-in peer-to-peer patch download system (unless you explicitly disabled it). Alternatively you can run a Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) and configure your clients to use WSUS which caches all patches.

Comment: Robert, Thank you for suggestion but we have downloaded those patches for fixing  vulnerability and dont have wsus for this group of systems.

Comment: Tried this link , but it supports only .msu files https://superuser.com/questions/1270990/need-a-batch-program-to-install-all-manually-downloaded-windows-updates-in-one-s